# Windows 10 not showing in grub after elementary OS installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub, microsoft-windows

I had Windows 10 installed on my drive now I installed elementary OS on a separate partition on the same drive. Both are on EFI system. The grub menu is not showing any option to boot to Windows only elementary OS is there. I tried boot-repair but it didn't work. I also tried manually editing the 40_custom file for a windows 10 menu entry but nothing seems to work. Please help me with this.

EDIT: Here is the pastebin link for boot-info summary

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bspZvmZSpg/

Comment: Have you tried to `sudo update-grub` ?

Comment: @a-tokarev yes I tried. grub is not fixing the issue.